# creating one instance of a class object for several private functions

Tags: c#, class, object

I want to create one instance of a class object to be used by several private functions in the same form. What I currently have is every function I create a new object like so:

```
 Player thePlayer = new Player(int.Parse(StrBox.Text), int.Parse(DexBox.Text), int.Parse(IntBox.Text), int.Parse(PerBox.Text), int.Parse(HPBox.Text), int.Parse(SPBox.Text), int.Parse(MPBox.Text), int.Parse(EXPBox.Text), int.Parse(ARBox.Text), int.Parse(CTHBox.Text), int.Parse(GoldBox.Text), int.Parse(MeleeDMGBox.Text), int.Parse(MagicDMGBox.Text), int.Parse(StealthBox.Text), int.Parse(DetectBox.Text), int.Parse(LevelBox.Text));
```

I have to put this into four different functions. You can see that it is a huge object with many variables. I want to be able to create it once for use by all objects because when I create a new variable I end up having to copy paste this beast all over my functions.

How can I do that? I'm new at OOP so this is what I tried to do, not knowing if it would work:

```
    public void PlayerInitialize()
    {
        string P = "p";
        Player thePlayer = new Player(int.Parse(StrBox.Text), int.Parse(DexBox.Text),      int.Parse(IntBox.Text), int.Parse(PerBox.Text), int.Parse(HPBox.Text), int.Parse(SPBox.Text), int.Parse(MPBox.Text), int.Parse(EXPBox.Text), int.Parse(ARBox.Text), int.Parse(CTHBox.Text), int.Parse(GoldBox.Text), int.Parse(MeleeDMGBox.Text), int.Parse(MagicDMGBox.Text), int.Parse(StealthBox.Text), int.Parse(DetectBox.Text), int.Parse(LevelBox.Text), P);
    }
  private void AddStrButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 Player thePlayer;
        //int Str, int Dex, int Intel, int Per, int HP, int SP, int MP, int EXP, int AR, int CTH, int Gold, int MelDMG, int MagDMG, int Stlth, int Det
        //Player thePlayer = new Player(int.Parse(StrBox.Text), int.Parse(DexBox.Text), int.Parse(IntBox.Text), int.Parse(PerBox.Text), int.Parse(HPBox.Text), int.Parse(SPBox.Text), int.Parse(MPBox.Text), int.Parse(EXPBox.Text), int.Parse(ARBox.Text), int.Parse(CTHBox.Text), int.Parse(GoldBox.Text), int.Parse(MeleeDMGBox.Text), int.Parse(MagicDMGBox.Text), int.Parse(StealthBox.Text), int.Parse(DetectBox.Text), int.Parse(LevelBox.Text), );


        if (thePlayer.StatPoints >= 1 && thePlayer.Strength <= 7)
        {
            thePlayer.Strength++;
            thePlayer.StatPoints--;
            thePlayer.HitPoints += 6;
            thePlayer.MeleeDMG += 2;
            StrBox.Text = thePlayer.Strength.ToString();
            SPBox.Text = thePlayer.StatPoints.ToString();
            HPBox.Text = thePlayer.HitPoints.ToString();
            MeleeDMGBox.Text = thePlayer.MeleeDMG.ToString();
        }
        else if (thePlayer.Strength >= 8)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the limits of your mortal abilities.");
        }
        else if (thePlayer.StatPoints <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Earn more experience!");
        }
        /*
        MessageBox.Show("PCStats.StatPoints equals" + PCStats.StatPoints);
        MessageBox.Show("PCStats,Strength equals" + PCStats.Strength);
        MessageBox.Show("IntPCSP Equals" + IntPCSP.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("IntPCStr Equals" + IntPCStr.ToString());
        */
    }
```

Unfortunately I get the following error: Use of unassigned local variable 'thePlayer'

Any ideas for how I can create the object once instead of every time I use it in a function?

Here is the class sheet for further reference:

```
 namespace PlayerPC
{
class Player
{
    public void PlayerGraphic(string pcGraphic)
    {
    PCGraphic = pcGraphic;
    }
    //player stats
    public Player(int Str, int Dex, int Intel, int Per, int HP, int SP, int MP, int EXP, int AR, int CTH, int Gold, int MelDMG, int MagDMG, int Stlth, int Det, int Lvl, string pcGraphic)
    {
        Strength = Str;
        Dexterity = Dex;
        Intelligence = Intel;
        Perception = Per;
        HitPoints = HP;
        StatPoints = SP;
        MindPoints = MP;
        ExperiencePoints = EXP;
        Armor = AR;
        ChanceToHit = CTH;
        GoldCoins = Gold;
        MeleeDMG = MelDMG;
        MagicDMG = MagDMG;
        Stealth = Stlth;
        Detect = Det;
        Level = Lvl;
        PCGraphic = pcGraphic;
    }
    public bool LevelUp()
    {
        if(this.Level == 1 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 25)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 2 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 125)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 3 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 625)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 4 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 1125)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 5 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 1850)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 6 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 2900)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 7 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 4500)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 8 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 5800)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 9 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 8200)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 10 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 12800)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 11 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 16200)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.Level == 12 && this.ExperiencePoints >= 25000)
        {
            this.Level++;
            this.StatPoints++;
            MessageBox.Show("You have accended to Level " + this.Level);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int Strength {get; set; }
    public int Dexterity { get; set; }
    public int Intelligence { get; set; }
    public int Perception { get; set; }
    public int HitPoints { get; set; }
    public int StatPoints { get; set; }
    public int MindPoints { get; set; }
    public int ExperiencePoints { get; set; }
    public int Armor { get; set; }
    public int ChanceToHit { get; set; }
    public int GoldCoins { get; set; }
    public int MeleeDMG { get; set; }
    public int MagicDMG { get; set; }
    public int Stealth { get; set; }
    public int Detect { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public string PCGraphic { get; set; }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `private` field of the Player `class` and use it in your various methods.

Example:

```
public class TheClassThatUseThePlayerObject
{
    private Player thePlayer = new Player(int.Parse(StrBox.Text), int.Parse(DexBox.Text), int.Parse(IntBox.Text), int.Parse(PerBox.Text), int.Parse(HPBox.Text), int.Parse(SPBox.Text), int.Parse(MPBox.Text), int.Parse(EXPBox.Text), int.Parse(ARBox.Text), int.Parse(CTHBox.Text), int.Parse(GoldBox.Text), int.Parse(MeleeDMGBox.Text), int.Parse(MagicDMGBox.Text), int.Parse(StealthBox.Text), int.Parse(DetectBox.Text), int.Parse(LevelBox.Text));

    public void FirstMethod()
    {
        thePlayer.DoSomething();
    }
    public void SecondMethod()
    {
        thePlayer.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Read more about fields:[Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @PaulWilliamFassett You're welcome, look at my updated answer with the code example.

Comment: So only problem I see above is that I wont be able to pull StrBox.Text because it is on another form. If I knew how to share data between forms, I could probably fix, and troubleshoot just about anything I am doing wrong, but I have yet to find a detailed tutorial on how to do that. Instead I get this error:

StrBox does not exist in it's current context.

Comment: @PaulWilliamFassett I think that link might help: [Sharing data among Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325000/Sharing-data-among-Windows-Forms)

Answer (score 2):

Put the line `Player thePlayer;` outside the method definition, directly into the class and prefix it with `private`.

The get a book about OOP and read the basics.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem, and when I have 40 dollars to drop on something other than food, I'll get a book. As it stands, that isn't an option. I've been learning through vague video tutorials, and piecing the logic together in my mind as I go. Is this not the right place to go to ask questions?

Comment: It is, it is: What I meant is: Get a book, this will tell you **why**.  My method should really fix your problem, please tell me what error you get - there might be another error somewhere!

Comment: I think you are right though. I just watched a purely OOP video, and I think I know why this is happening, but still a bit fuzzy on some other things. I think I don't need the constructor in the class file. Because the properties are defined for Player, I can just get and set from the other form without creating that long form instance every time. So thank you for that.